# Bash script that prints statistics about text files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to write a Linux bash script that will help me generate some statistics that I need from text files. Assume the following format in the text files that I am using:

```
"string : pathname1 : pathname2 : pathname3 : … pathnameN"
```

Where pathname " i " is the full path of the file in which I found a specific string. For example, such a file could look like this:

**logile.txt**

```
string : "version" pathname1: /home/Desktop/myfile.txt pathname2 : /usr/lib/tmp/sample.txt 

string : "user" pathname1 : temp1/tmpfiles/user.txt  pathname2 : newfile.txt pathname3 : /Downloads/myfiles/old/credentials.txt

string : "admin" pathname1 : 

string: "build" pathname1 : Documents/projects/myproject/readme.txt pathname2 
 : Desktop/readmetoo.txt
```

In this example, I would like my bash script to inform me that I searched for a total of 4 words (version,user,admin,build) and also that the word that was found in most  files was "user", which was found in 3 files. Is using "awk" command a good approach? I am not familiar with bash scripts,so any help would be useful! Thanks!

Comment: Format of this `logile.txt` is inconsistent. The line in `logile.txt` has a format of `string : pathname1 :pathname2 ...` or `string: pathname1: pathname2: ` or `string: pathname1: path pathname2: path` (please notice spaces between doublepoints and words)?

Comment: @KamilCuk thx for the notice, I edited the format!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: While it's a bit of a bad form to say "use something else", I'll do so - while you can do a lot with bash (as Kamil demonstrates below), doing the same in Perl, Python or Ruby would be much, much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not such an easy task, it can be probably done in awk alone, but you were asking about bash script. The following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

wordcount=0
tmp=""
# for each line in input file read 3 fields
while read string name rest; do
    # in each line the first word should be equal to string
    if [ "$string" != string ]; then 
        # if it isn't continue to the next line
        continue; 
    fi
    # remove '"' from name
    name=${name//\"}
    # the rest has a format of pathname <path> 
    # substitute every space with newline in the rest 
    # and remove lines containing pathname'i' 
    # to get only paths in the rest
    rest=$(echo "$rest" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -v "pathname" ||:)
    # count the lines in rest, each path should be in different line
    restcnt=$(wc -l <<<"$rest")
    # save restcnt and name in single line in tmp string to parse later
    tmp+="$restcnt $name"$'\n'
    # increment wordcount
    wordcount=$[$wordcount+1]

# feed while read loop with a command substitution
done < <(
    # cat stdin or file given as script argument
    # and substitude all doublepoints ':' with spaces
    cat "$@" | sed 's/:/ /g'
)

# sort the tmp string from the lowest to biggest
# and get last line (ie. biggest number
tmp=$(echo "$tmp" | sort -n | tail -n1)
# split tmp into two variables - the word and the count
read mostcnt mostfile <<<"$tmp"

# and print user information
echo "You searched for a total of $wordcount words."
echo "The word that was found in most files was: $mostfile"
echo " which was found in $mostcnt files."
```

... run with the input from the following `logile.txt` ...

```
string : "version" pathname1:/home/Desktop/myfile.txt pathname2 : /usr/lib/tmp/sample.txt

string : "user" pathname1: temp1/tmpfiles/user.txt pathname2: newfile.txt pathname3: /Downloads/myfiles/old/credentials.txt

string : "admin" pathname1 :

string: "build" pathname1: Documents/projects/myproject/readme.txt pathname2:Desktop/readmetoo.txt
```

... produces the following result:

```
$ /tmp/1.sh <./logile.txt 
You searched for a total of 4 words.
The word that was found in most files was: user
 which was found in 6 files.
```

Comment: thx a lot for your time and your response! A small correction, though. User is found 3 times in this example, as shown in the logfile. namely: pathname1 pathname2 and pathname3